# Python says else has invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure if it's just because I'm not very good at this but what's happening is I'm trying to get

```
jug = input('Welcome to the 1-99 site swap generator. Enter a number 
between/including 1 and 99 and I will determine whether or not it is possible to juggle it')
juggl = int(jug)

juggle = jug % 3

if juggle = 0
print ("It's very possible to juggle this! Have fun!")
else print("Unfortunately that is not possible :(")
```

What's happening is, in 'juggle = 0'  it's saying = is being used in the wrong context and then tells me to instead use a colon. However if I were to replace = with a colon

ex.

```
juggle : 0
```

it presents me with an error and instead says else has invalid syntax

Comment: Your code is incorrectly indented. How does it tells you to use a colon? What is the exact error message?

Comment: If you don't understand basic operators than you should go back to the basics and fundamentals. Such a question is discouraged here on SO because it can be fixed simply by doing research.

Comment: Yeah, let's brow-beat a coding newbie, because that's how we lift up new members of the coding community! Don't let them grind you down, Aj. Hit up some Python tutorials. It's an easy enough language, but it's one of the few that uses this funky formatting.

Comment: How am I, in any way shape or form, brow-beating the OP? I'm giving him some advice on what not to ask here. You even said it yourself, *Hit up some Python tutorials. It's an easy enough language* (Which is subjective and in my opinion, a completely wrong statement.) @kayleeFrye_onDeck , I'm giving him a critique, which tells him what is discouraged here and that it can be fixed easily. I'm also telling him to do research before coming here. I'm not putting down the OP nor making fun or joking about his level of understanding.

Comment: I was referring to the insta-downvotes... but okay!

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck The same principle applies. Insta-downvotes are because the question is off-topic and not suitable for the site. That's why they attract downvotes. If a question is a good, constructive, and an on-topic one we will recognize that and respond accordingly

Comment: It was a debugging question with an error being thrown at the end of the script without providing preceding error info to an obviously new coder (check his profile). If you can't sympathize with that, you're too far down the rabbit hole to remember what it's like to start fresh. If people want to downvote, its their points, whatever. Steamrolling newbies annoys me. To each their own.

Comment: We're not steamrolling newbies. Heck, we're helping them by saving the time by telling them to refrain from asking until they've done their part (by researching). I love that new people come to the community, but you have to ask yourself, *if this certain question is displayed, what will it reflect about the site?* If the answer is a positive impact, then great. If not, then the question should be reviewed, edited and researched before asking. This same error may very well been answered on this site. @kayleeFrye_onDeck

Comment: Everyone here was a beginner at some point. With the luxury of search engines like Google, it's easy to do your research before coming.

Comment: I agree with kaylee.  I think you're being to hard on AJ.  If you're a beginner you don't know the right way to ask.  A downvote is a bit harsh.  Just answer the poor fellow and suggest a better way to solve this type of problem in the future.

Comment: Inaccurate reason, please find a more valid one for debugging than this, "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Answer (score 3):

You would need a : after the if and else statements, and indents to specify what's occurring inside those blocks. Also, equality in python is checked with an "==" rather an a single "=". Here's the updated code that should work,

```
if juggle == 0:
    print ("It's very possible to juggle this! Have fun!")
else:
    print("Unfortunately that is not possible :(")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a few issues here:

- `=` (assignment) vs `==` (comparison)
- colon at the end of the `if` statement is missing
- you should indent the block which contains the `print` statement

  ```
  if juggle == 0:
       print("text")
  else:
       print("something else")
  ```

Comment: EDIT: sorry the code wasn't formatted well in the first submission

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part should look as follows:

```
if juggle == 0:
    print ("It's very possible to juggle this! Have fun!")
else:
    print("Unfortunately that is not possible :(")
```

The 'if' statement has the general structure:

```
if:
   ...
elif:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

if *condition*: (the colon must follow to tell the Python interpreter what it should do when the 'if' condition is met). Also, since variable assignment is done with '=' in programming, equality tests are conducted with '=='.

Answer (score 0):

There are three mistakes in the following:

```
if juggle = 0
print ("It's very possible to juggle this! Have fun!")
else print("Unfortunately that is not possible :(")
```

First off:

1. Just one "=" means that you are assigning a value to juggle, if you want to compare, you should use "==" (two equals)
2. At the end of your condition, you should put a ":"
3. Indentention is part of python programing, it delimits the beginning and end of your code.

So, for your code to work, try this:

```
if juggle = 0:
    print ("It's very possible to juggle this! Have fun!")
else: 
    print("Unfortunately that is not possible :(")
```